# Gcc inline ASM, set EBX to char array address using LEA

Tags: gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

I'm trying to convert an inline asm code form VS to GCC (AT&T).. the original code is this one:

```
char mystr[] = "Hello world";
_asm mov eax,0
_asm lea ebx, [mystr]
```

Here is my attempt to convert that code in gcc at&t syntax:

```
char mystr[] = "Hello world";
asm("mov $0,%%eax\n"
    "leal (%0),%%ebx\n"
    : : "r"(mystr));
```

This code doesn't seems to work, any idea why ? 
Thank you very much

Comment: What errors are you getting? What does `gcc -c -S file.c` generate?

Comment: Well, after the lea line there is a call to int 0x80 (that I haven't written here), that call, call a sort of printf. (I'm doisng some kernel stuff for an university exam). I don't get errors, but it looks like that the address of mystr is not correctly written in ebx, since I can't see the string displayed on the screen..

Comment: : : "r"(mystr)); tells gcc that %ebx has been clobbered, its content cannot be used afterwards. You need to put `mystr` on the output list instead  "r"(mystr)) : : ;. Btw, what about the change to %eax?

Comment: uhm, I've to write the address of the mystr in ebx, so why I've to put mystrl in the output ? :/ .. As for eax, it is correct, it should contain 0 ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code seems to works:

```
char* mystr = "Hello world";

asm("mov $0,%%eax\n"
    "leal (%0),%%ebx"
    ::"b"(mystr));
```

I've changed char mystr[] to char* mystr, and "r" with "b"..
If somebody know what "b" does exactly, please let me know...
many thanks

Comment: the `b` constraint changes the register that holds your value. See documentation (http://ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html#ss6.1).